# How to set boolean to true if report is downloaded once in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I need to set boolean value as true, if user click on button under the print menu to download report.
In mrp, i created a boolean field in transfers form. While clicking on transfers it traversed to picking form. If user download report in picking form, boolean field is set to true which is in transfers form.

Could anyone please help me?

In below code, i need to auto update the field generated_report when generated set to true.

Code:

```
    class ReportGeneration(models.Model):
        _inherit='stock.picking'
        generated=fields.Boolean(string='Generated')
        def mark_boolean_true(self):
            self.generated = True
    
    class ReportGen(models.Model):
        _inherit='mrp.production'
        generated_report=fields.Boolean(string='Generated', store= True, compute = 'get')
        ref = fields.Char(string='Ref', readonly=True, related='name')
        @api.depends('ref')
        def get(self):
            if self.state != 'confirmed':
                for mo in self:
                    if mo.ref:
                        so=self.env['stock.picking'].search([('origin','=',mo.ref)])
# until this works fine
                        @api.onchange('so.generated')
                        def _onchange(self):
                            if so.generated:
                                mo.generated_report = so.generated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call python method from xml view and marked the boolean as True.
You can call python method from .xml like as mention below.

```
<t t-set="temp" t-value="o.mark_boolean_true()"></t>
```

write below code in transfer object.py.

```
def mark_boolean_true(self):
    self.boolean_field = True
```

Comment: how could i give xpath while inheriting the delivery slip report. We are setting t value right! Could you please tell me how should i do that?

Comment: Is it possible to call a function from mrp model in delivery slip report?

Comment: For xpath: https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/inheriting-and-modifying-qweb-reports/

Comment: I'm not getting your second question, can you please describe in detail with some code if possible.

Comment: I'm having a boolean field1 in stock_picking form. If qweb generated it sets that boolean to true. But i need to update the value of boolean field2  automatically in mrp production form only when boolean field1 is set to true

Comment: okay, What if you search the MO(Mrp Production) record from the same method(mark_boolean_true) and mark the boolean as TRUE. No need to wirte compute filed then.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help sir. I got a help and made it done.@hardik